# plotting mixed effect model interaction in ggplot with three levels of IV

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have ran the following mixed effects model and would now like to visualise it:

```
mod_father_son <- lmer(AIP_s_child.z ~ AIP_s_parent.z*Q_mean.z + 
                  (1 + AIP_s_parent.z:Q_mean.z || Family_number), 
                data = data_father_son)
```

There is a significant interaction between AIP_s_parentz and Q_means.z and after speaking to a supervisor he advised me to plot the interaction showing three regression lines for 3 levels of an IV (AIP_s_parent.z or Q_mean.z), and to use predict(). However, being very bad at ggplot2 I have no idea where to even start. I've tried to figure it out using some of the code available in other questions here but with no luck. Both IVs are continuous and transformed into respective z-scores.

The data set looks like this:

```
Id_parent   Family_number   AIP_s_parent.z   Q_mean.z   Child_id   AIP_s_child.z

A1          1               -.008            -0.5       B1         .005
A1          1               -.008            -0.5       B2         .04
C1          2                .06             -.006      D1         -.007
E1          3               -.1              0.02       F1         -.06
```

I'm afraid I can't provide a full data set for ethical reasons.

Comment: you can check this package there are some premade plot  `http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.lmer/`

Comment: Thanks, but the package is clashing with other packages I have loaded unfortunately.

Comment: Are you able to provide data / make this a reproducible example?

Comment: Have now added a sample data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for providing the data. I think this website will help you a great deal 
[[Plotting predicted values from lmer as a single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763089/plotting-predicted-values-from-lmer-as-a-single-plot][1])

This shows how to plot from lmer objects using the effects package and ggplot2.

Here is some sample code I put together- I had to add extra rows (made up on my part) so I could get your model to converge. Hope this helps.

```
   library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)
library(effects)

#fake data
data_father_son <- data.frame(Id_parent = c("A1","A1","C1", "E1", "H1", "H2", "A","L","K", "Z"),
                              Family_number = c(1,1,2,3,1:6),
                              AIP_s_parent.z = c(-.008,-.008,.06,-.008,-.008,.06,-.008,-.008,.06,.06),
                              Q_mean.z = c(-.5,-.5,-.006, .02, 4:9),
                              Child_id = c("B1","B2","D1", "F1", "A1", "A3","E4","P1","L9","I0"),
                              AIP_s_child.z = c(.005,.04,-.007,-.06, .1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6),
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#model
mod_father_son <- lmer(AIP_s_child.z ~ AIP_s_parent.z*Q_mean.z + 
                         (1 + AIP_s_parent.z:Q_mean.z || Family_number), 
                       data = data_father_son)
#getting effects for the two variables and creating a df
ee <- as.data.frame(Effect(c("AIP_s_parent.z","Q_mean.z"),mod = mod_father_son))

#plot
ggplot(ee, aes(AIP_s_parent.z,fit, group=Q_mean.z, color = Q_mean.z))+
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Is there any way you can change the lines to different types rather than colour? When I try it I get an error as it's a continuous variable. The plot must be black and white unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you have to change the Q_mean.z variable to a character - code below `ee <- mutate(ee, Q_mean.z = as.character(Q_mean.z))
#plot
ggplot(ee, aes(AIP_s_parent.z,fit, group=Q_mean.z, linetype = Q_mean.z))+
    geom_line()`